# Nested Case Statement for multiple condition

Tags: sql

I have a data set like bellow image.
I need in the data set
Grade Red is present then in `OpenSegment=yes` if not but
Grade Amber is present then in `OpenSegment=yes` if not but
Grade Blue is present then in `OpenSegment=yes`

for that I write

```
 COALESCE(
                  CASE WHEN airag.FK_MasterRAGRatingID=1 THEN 'yes' ELSE '' END,
                  CASE WHEN airag.FK_MasterRAGRatingID=2 THEN 'yes' ELSE '' END,
                 CASE WHEN airag.FK_MasterRAGRatingID=4 THEN 'yes' ELSE '' END
                )
```

but not working.

[image]

**Result after putting  `ELSE NULL`**

[image]

Comment: update it by `ELSE NULL`

Comment: I removed all those dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms you're actually using.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: We need both sample table data and the expected result.

Comment: just change your last `case`.. `else` part with `' '`

Answer (score 4):

I don't even think you need three separate `CASE` expressions here:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN airag.FK_MasterRAGRatingID IN (1, 2, 4) THEN 'yes' END AS OpenSegment
    -- other columns
FROM yourTable
```

The above logic should work whether or not the table you showed us is derived.

The default `ELSE` condition for a `CASE` expression is `NULL`.  Hence the above would label open segments of non matching rows as `NULL`.  If you want to use a different value, then provide an explicit `ELSE`:

```
CASE WHEN airag.FK_MasterRAGRatingID IN (1, 2, 4) THEN 'yes' ELSE '' END
```

This would assume you want to use empty string, but it could be any value.

Answer (score 1):

Good answer by Tim Biegeleisen but looking at the question shouldn't you do the case when on the Grade column instead of ID?

So code would be;

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN airag.Grade IN ('Red', 'Amber', 'Blue') THEN 'yes' END AS OpenSegment
    -- other columns
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: It depends on to what the `FK_MasterRAGRatingID` corresponds.  It would be preferable perhaps to use a grade ID over a name, because perhaps two different IDs have the same color.

Comment: True, but based on the way he asked it "I need in the data set
Grade Red is present" So it looks like a selection on colour not on ID.

Comment: Maybe I was naiive and took the original code too literally +1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, `COALESCE` is used for First `Not NULL` Value, if you give `EMPTY('')` in the else part, it consider the column has some value.

So you have to use `NULL` instead of ''.

```
COALESCE(
                  CASE WHEN airag.FK_MasterRAGRatingID=1 THEN 'yes' ELSE NULL END,
                  CASE WHEN airag.FK_MasterRAGRatingID=2 THEN 'yes' ELSE NULL END,
                 CASE WHEN airag.FK_MasterRAGRatingID=4 THEN 'yes' ELSE NULL END
                )
```

IF we want Empty in the NULL columns, we have to use like below:

```
ISNULL(COALESCE(
                  CASE WHEN airag.FK_MasterRAGRatingID=1 THEN 'yes' ELSE NULL END,
                  CASE WHEN airag.FK_MasterRAGRatingID=2 THEN 'yes' ELSE NULL END,
                 CASE WHEN airag.FK_MasterRAGRatingID=4 THEN 'yes' ELSE NULL END
                ),'')
```

Hope this is what you need:

```
SELECT ISNULL(CASE WHEN airag.FK_MasterRAGRatingID=1 THEN 'yes' 
        ELSE  
         CASE WHEN airag.FK_MasterRAGRatingID=2 THEN 'yes'
         ELSE
          CASE WHEN airag.FK_MasterRAGRatingID=4 THEN 'yes' ELSE NULL END END  END
,'')
```

Comment: please see Result after putting ELSE NULL ,the result is wrong .

Comment: What's wrong with the result? Do you need empty values in the NULL columns? Try my updated answer.

Comment: Used your 2nd code but for that except green for all other print yes.

Comment: Because we give all the other columns in the case statement

Comment: Can you please tell, what result you need. I'll try

Comment: So ,I need in the data set
Grade Red is present then in OpenSegment=yes if not but Grade Amber is present then in OpenSegment=yes if not but Grade Blue is present then in OpenSegment=yes that means only one yes present for each time.